# Grails 2.1.1 and spring security messages

Tags: grails-2.1

Anyone experiencing the error messages for failed logins not appearing?

I am upgrading a grails 1.3.7 app to grails 2.1.1 and I have 2 issues with the spring security core functionality.

First, if I try an invalid login the auth fails but there is no error message just {} in the flash message.

Second,  I was using a method like this to get the current count of active sessions.  It no longer is accurate, as it just increases and doesn't recognize a logout.

```
def getCurrentSessionCount(){
    def sessioncount = 0
    sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().each{
        sessioncount += sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(it, false).size()
    }
    return sessioncount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay well this was a difference in the LoginController how the error messages were getting populated.  In 1.3.7 and previous security plugin the code looks like:

```
msg = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.errors.login.expired
```

but for 2.1.1 and the upgraded spring security plugin 1.2.7.3  the code needs to use the context like:

```
msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.disabled")
```

The session count has to do with a modification to the web.xml that you need to make to add the session listener, however in the new spring 3.0 it was moved so the new entry should look like:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```